# Show only the first x li's without using ngFor in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 9 `<li>` elements in my template, every one of them has a *ngIf condition.

It's possible that 5 of them return true or maybe more or less, but i want to display only the first 4 or less if the case.

The order of the `<li>` is the priority

I tried this:

```
// Template
<li *ngIf="checkCond(profile.Projects.length != 0)">Example</li>
... and so on...

// Component
shown: number = 0;

public checkCond(value: boolean): boolean {
    if (value) {
        this.shown += 1;
        return this.shown <= 4;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

The problem with my aproach is that `if (value)` will fire continuously, and will get incremented way more than 9 as I expected, therefore in the end it will return only false;

I don't want to use *ngFor

Comment: "I don't want to use *ngFor"..why?

Comment: @PetrAdam the logic doesn't allow me, I have overlays, translations, and other stuff

Comment: If I understand you're problem you need to show no more than 4 elements but maybe not all 4 of them, and in the meanwhile you need to se if that element is visible?

Comment: @mautrok exactly  :)

Comment: What tirgger such event? because you can store you're four objects in a map, and give them an attribute (like object.show=true). I ogten had to do such things, know you're porpose can help me to help you:)

Comment: You could also create a custom pipe which limits an array to 4 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkCond()` will be called every time change detection runs

instead assing the result to a property and bind to that property

```
constructor() { // or somewhere else
  this.checkCond(profile.Projects.length != 0);
}

cond:boolean;

public checkCond(value: boolean): boolean {
    if (value) {
        this.shown += 1;
        this.cond this.shown <= 4;
    }
    else this.cond = false;
}
```

```
<li *ngIf="cond">Example</li>
```

Comment: But checkCond will set "cond" everytime, you mean I should create a checkCond for every li?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Just call `checkCond` when `value` changes. This updates `cond` and Angular updates your view (but only updates when necessary - not on every change detection cycle.

Comment: Doesn't show anything, what about the conditions on the other <li>  what condition did you had in mind?

Comment: The one `checkCond` assigns to in my answer. I just added the field explicitly in my answer.

Comment: I can't see how this could work, So I get something like this
  `this.checkCond(this.profile.Projects.length != 0);
  this.checkCond(this.profile.Schools.length != 0);
  this.checkCond(this.profile.Study.length != 0);
  this.checkCond(this.profile.Websites.length != 0);
  this.checkCond(this.profile.Languages.length != 0);
  this.checkCond(this.profile.Hobby.length != 0);`
and the li's will be :

`<li *ngIf="cond">Projects</li>
<li *ngIf="cond">Companies</li>
<li *ngIf="cond">Schools</li>`
...

Comment: That code helps to understand what you try to accomplish. Create an object like `conds = [{name: Projects, cond: this.profile.Projects.length != 0}, {name: Schools, cond: this.profile.Schools.length != 0, ...}]` and then use `<ng-container *ngFor="let item of conds"><li *ngIf="item.cond">{{item.name}} - {{profile[name].xxx}}</li></ng-container>` (where `xxx` is a property of the profile element you might want to display)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use hardcode of this type, I think that you should create a array and iterator in your component, f.e.

```
someArray: boolean[] = [true, true, true, false, false, false];
someIterator: number = 0;
```

and in your HTML code:

```
...<li *ngIf="someArray[someIterator]">Example 1</li>
{{someIterator = someIterator + 1}}
<li *ngIf="someArray[someIterator]">Example 2</li>
{{someIterator = someIterator + 1}}...
```

But its very dirty solution. For such cases there is NgFor.

Last idea for me is using @ViewChildren or @ContentChildren. Ar you trying that?